# TableView And Viewcontroller button refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm a beginner in Swift I've trying to figure something out, I have a TextField and Button on the ViewController, and on the VC I have TableView that's slightly showing the VC where the text field and button are in the TableView there is a TableViewCell with a Label. So when the app runs I need to be able to put something in the text field and then click the button it should show that string in the label that was in the TVCell. When there is no input it should show a default string.

So far what I had was an empty array with a button action that had an if-else statement the code would run but nothing would show up in the cell after I entered and pressed the button. It was adding that string in the array but it wouldn't print out in the cells. I had the rows set to the array.count.

UIKIT and Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

So I figure it out I connect the UITableView to ViewController and then in my if else I called tableView.reload().